# how to round DecimalFormat in java (android)

Tags: java, android, rounding

I want to round

```
0.005 to 0.01
```

im using this code

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

but the answer keeps getting `0.00`
I want only 2 digits on the right with rounding if possible
anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add the `RoundingMode` for the DecimalFormat

```
double d = 0.005;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(df.format(d)); //0.01
```

Comment: why i cant add                 import java.math.RoundingMode;

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: fix the add round but why i cant setRoundingMode;  it dosent show!

Comment: You need API level 9 to use RoundingMode

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit the question and add your actual code

Comment: @NickT  thanks  now i know why its not working,,, im using android 2.1 not 2.3

Answer (score 0):

For rounding use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(number);
decimal = decimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String result = decimal.toString();
```